# Saving images in a folder

Tags: android

```
 int count=1;
    if(block=="other(from camera)")
    {
            final String dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/picFolder/"; 
            File newdir = new File(dir); 
            newdir.mkdirs();

             int TAKE_PHOTO_CODE = 0;
             count++;
             file = dir+count+".jpg";
             File newfile = new File(file);
             try 
             {newfile.createNewFile();} 
             catch (IOException e) {}       

             Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(newfile);

             Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
             cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
             startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
```

**This is a code for taking the picture and saving it to the gallery.and I want to use the images which are getting stored.But unfortunately everytime I close the app and reopen it, the pictures starts again from 2.jpeg.Is there a way such that the pictures are taken in continuation even after reopening the app.**

Comment: You are comparing strings with ==, incrementing a local variable, not checking the result of mkdirs() and follow very *unconventional* formatting rules for both code and text. Please, help us to help you

Comment: actually this is just a sample code.right now I just want to come out of the problem then afterwards i can optimize it.